# Php MySQL import csv returns query, not adding to database

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

I am trying to import a csv file with php and save it to mysql database. Things were working well, and suddenly there seems to be a problem.

When I try to upload the file this is the result (there are 190 fields, but I am just showing a summary of what is returned when I upload):

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_preschool`(`met_on`, `institution_name`, `slug`, `address`, `landmark`, `area`, `region`, `district_city`) VALUES ('','','','','','1298','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
```

As I said, it was working fine when I checked it once, then all of a sudden things broke down. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Check your csv file, that's were you'll find the problem

Comment: If it works well then you must edit code some where? is it so? otherwise you can follow this: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/import-export-csv-using-php-and-mysql/

Comment: That's where I got it from. I am not sure where what is causing this error. How can I check where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use right syntax while inserting data, instead of using ' only

change

```
'','','','','','1298','',*'*,'',
```

to

```
'','','','','','1298','',*''*,'',
```

where * * contains your corrected values

Answer (score 0):

You missed one closing quote here `'1298','',',` change this with

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_preschool`(`met_on`, `institution_name`, `slug`, `address`, `landmark`, `area`, `region`, `district_city`) VALUES ('','','','','','1298','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
```

Comment: Hi, the single quote was my typo, I think. I have updated the result that I get. I have checked twice, but I don't think I've missed any quotations.